# Can't select button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm trying to select

`<input type="button" class="set_image_btn" value="Set image" />`

with

`$('.set_image_btn').live("click", function(){
            alert('CLICKED!');
        });`

but for some reason it won't work. The HTML is made by JavaScript in my HTML file and I suspect my .js file is unable to get this, but I'm not sure how to properly select it.

Comment: Did Firebug or other javascript debugger shows an error?

Comment: are you sure you have included jquery properly?  I am able to make it work with the code provided. http://jsfiddle.net/5jdfd/1/

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing more code. Are you sure the live function is getting called?

Comment: Code works but make it sure to refer correctly to the jquyer library.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling the code **after** you created the html with javascript, so you'd have something like this:

```
$('<input type="button" ...').appendTo("body"); //I asume you create with it.
alert($('.set_image_btn').size()); //This is a test alert. Should alert '1'
$('.set_image_btn').live("click", function(){ alert('CLICKED!'); });
```

If the test alert alerts '0' it means you didn't create the element or you didn't append it to the page.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: OP is using `live` so it does not matter when the element is created.